# Line-height works differently on Mac and Windows

Tags: css, font-face

I have a text with non web font, I have used `@font-face` for this.

It's working fine in all browsers on Windows, but top aligned in all browsers on Mac.

[image]

Blue box in this image is line-height.

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375822/font-face-and-line-height-issue), but it doesn't provide a workable solution.

Comment: do you have the font in question installed on either machine?  just an initial thought.

Comment: This other SO post might help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442910/line-height-not-vertically-centering-text-on-mac-but-looks-fine-on-windows)

Comment: If this is a web font, try to normalize the line-height settings in the font file using the Font Squirrel [Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator); it has an option to  "Fix Vertical Metrics
(Normalize across browsers)"; That might fix it (depending on the font)

Answer (score 5):

If it is resolved by using a different font the issue is with the font, not with the CSS.

Font squirrel has an option under 'expert' where you can check 'Auto-Adjust Vertical Metrics' this might work for you.

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 4):

You can convert fonts, using https://transfonter.org/ with the "Fix vertical metrics" option enabled, solved my problem.

Comment: it can't to fix metrics in .otf font

Answer (score 0):

We had a bug where vertical scrollbars appeared in Windows and no other operating systems.  We soon figured out that setting `line-height` has different effects in different browsers, **especially** if you use a `system` `font-family`:

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Noto Sans", Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}
```

The differing `line-height` problem can be solved by:

1. A **unitless** `line-height`: for example: `1.2`, `1.5`, etc..  Double-check in other operating systems the differences, as the impact on the visual line height can vary from operating system to operating system.
2. No `line-height` at all.  Reconsider why you have `line-height` in the first place and whether you should really just override it on the `body` and leave the rest to the renderer.
3. Applying `overflow-y: hidden` on the container as a last resort if you **must** have consistency across all browsers.

But really, why use a `system` font if you don't expect differences?