# Line-Height not vertically centering text on Mac but looks fine on Windows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a page that displays the size of your browser page. The problem lies with the text displaying the height and width of the browser. While the text aligns perfectly on Windows computers they appear severely off when viewing on Macs. Its also worth noting this issue occurs when using an external resource (http://fonts.com) to generate the desired font 'Rockwell Extra Bold'.

**Site Link:** http://howbigismybrowser.com/

The essential CSS of the container holding the text is as follows:

```
#display: {
    background: #232323; border: 15px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Rockwell W01 Extra Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 4.063em;
    text-align: center;
    height: 170px;
    line-height: 170px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**Update:**

'display: table' applied but for some reason font has extra space at the bottom. Doesn't appear to be extra margin or padding.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be that the line-height of the font you're using is rendered differently as you've already suggested. I tried changing the font-family in the inspector: some fonts work well using the line-height trick, others don't. What about other ways of vertical centring, like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
#display {
    /* line-height: 170px; */
    /* height: 170px; */
    display: table;
    [...]
}

#width, #height {
    /* float: left; */
    /* height: 100%; */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

No doubt, you'll need to fix some other styling, but this can be an effective way of doing the same thing but not relying on line-height.

Reference: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: The table method appears to solve the problem but there's just a few things that stand in the way. The font is adding extra space at the bottom, push down the original height of its parent container. I attached a screenshot in the op.